# Is it safe to secure URL parameters via a hashed key?

Tags: php, security

I want to let users share data outside of their account and have put together a proof of concept that essentially generates a unique URL with relevant URL parameters to display the data.

Obviously, a normal URL would simply let you modify the parameters, modify the query and extract any data you wished. So, with this, when the user generates a link to share data, I take the parameters, add a complex salt, hash the combined string `(sha-2)` and then use that as a key. So the URL might look like:

`mydomain.com/app/shared.php?function=form&account=1&form=a19481e78dd87f5eb04afe94c85ea4f3&key=7dcaa38baa19e0f70262d8775582300346f5c544`

When the URL is entered, the server recompiles the parameters and the secret salt and validates the key. If the key is not valid, no data is displayed.

I did think about further securing this by storing parameters in a DB, so the URL looks more like `mydomain.com/app/h6Hs52ff2a`, and the parameters never directly included in the URL, but equally I quite like the idea of generating sharable URLs on the fly with no DB backend.

I get the sense that the above approach might be a little frowned upon, but equally, unless you know the salt stored on the server (which is itself complex) I can't see any way of bypassing such a system.

Thoughts most welcome.

Comment: If your params contain references to some data in DB you can't generate sharable URL with no DB backend. You should check if the user that is generating the URL is authorized to access referenced objects. So the second approach seems better because it gives you more control over generated urls. If your params contains data directly instead of references then is there a need to protect them? When someone modify the data in params he will just get gibberish results so there might not be a real motivation to modify params like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an entirely feasible approach, essentially a *signed URL*. The only weakness of that system is the secrecy of the salt/key; if you're using a fast hashing/encryption algorithm and a weak salt/key, it is feasible to brute-force the secret offline. So you'll need to use a strong (read: slow) enough algorithm to prevent that (a plain SHA2 is too fast!), and you need to ensure your key doesn't leak. You also need to ensure you don't lose your key accidentally, as that would reset all shared URLs. If this is done properly, it's a nice, stateless way to do things.

I'd look into [JWTs](https://jwt.io) as an alternative to your homegrown method, as they basically incorporate all your requirements already (they are essentially arbitrary signed data bags).

The advantage of the database approach is that it has no attack surface, and that you're able to invalidate shared URLs selectively. The drawback is that it uses database storage, which may have operational overhead.

One more deciding factor here would be URL-length, which you may or may not care about.

Comment: Thank you, and for your suggested considerations.

It made sense in my mind, but good to have your thoughts.

The DB backend does make a lot of sense - particularly in terms of controlling  and revoking access, but as you say it has the potential to grow pretty quickly. I have implemented the ability for data to be "unshared", but it's achieved at the record level as opposed to a separate table recording what has and hasn't been shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you need reassurance, it is the same concept employed by Google Drive when you share document with a link.

Some comments:

- Shared link readability. If the shared data is always about the same kind of model (for example account data), the link is OK. But if other types of data can be shared, like user details, I would include it in the URL so that the person getting the shared link can make some sense of the link.
- If you are concerned with adding more security, you can enforce a key per user. You would need to keep the key in the database for each user.
- When generating the url, add an expiry parameter and hash. When reading hashed link, you can then see if the link expired.
- Make sure to use URL safe characters

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you are trying to achieve makes me wonder, why don't you simply:

- map in your database a 128 bit random value to a set form parameters every time a user wishes to share a URL. It's as secure as the random number generator you use and the form values remain a secret (as they never leave the server).
- encrypt the parameters using a cipher with message authentication (authenticated encryption with modes like GCM or OCB). Secure unless your keys leak. Hides the form parameters from the eyes of the users.
- use only a part of 'authenticated encryption' like a message authentication code (MAC; HMAC). Does not hide the form parameters, adds a code that needs to be verified.